# how to print data of SUBSTRING_INDEX( ) field in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$qry=mysql_query(SELECT title,SUBSTRING_INDEX( blog, ' ', 15),user_id,date_time
FROM blog_tab WHERE status='Active');
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
  echo $res['blog'];

}
```

i use above query to show some content of paragraph in ma page but it do not allow to write the field which uses the function SUBSTRING_INDEX().how i can print the field of table with SUBSTRING_INDEX().

Answer (score 0):

Well, the column name in this case is not `blog`, it is `SUBSTRING_INDEX( blog, ' ', 15)`, so you would access it with `$res["SUBSTRING_INDEX( blog, ' ', 15)"]`, or since you are using `mysql_fetch_array` you can access it with `$res[1]`. However, I suggest you alias it, for easier acces, and use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, like:

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT title,SUBSTRING_INDEX( blog, ' ', 15) AS blog,user_id,date_time
FROM blog_tab WHERE status='Active'");
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
  echo $res['blog'];
}
```

**NOTE:** You should not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and will no longer be supported. Read more at https://www.php.net/mysql_query